# how to make Table C by Table A,B

Tags: mysql, database

### Question

how to make Table C  by Table A,B.
just on query.

ex) this query not working.

```
insert into C (mySring_A , mySring_B) 
values (any(select Table_A.mySring_A from Table_A) , 
        any(select Table_B. mySring_B from Table_B)
       );
```

### DB Table

Table_A
 + idx
 + mySring_A

Table_B
 + idx
 + mySring_B

Table_C
 + idx
 + mySring_A
 + mySring_B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert all combinations of strings from the two tables, use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into C(myString_A, myString_B)
    select a.myString_A, b.myString_B
    from Table_A a cross join
         Table_B b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Last i use query

```
insert into C(myString_A, myString_B)
    select distinct a.myString_A, b.myString_B
    from Table_A a cross join
         Table_B b
    where Table_A.myString_A = 'checkString';
```